# Semi-infinite intervals with rational endpoint topology

Tags: general-topology

I have to determine whether the family of sets
$$\tau = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\} \, \cup \, \{(a,+\infty), a \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$
is a topology or not. I have tried to give a family of elements of $\tau$ whose union is an interval of the form $(x, +\infty)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. For example, since the sequence $\{-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\}$ of rational numbers is decreasing and converges to $-e \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, then
$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n,+\infty) = (-e,+\infty)$$
which shows that $\tau$ is not a topology. Is this correct? If so, is there an easier approach to show that $\tau$ is not a topology?

Comment: Great example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct: Let $x\in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n,+\infty)$ then $-(1+1/n)^n<x$ for some $n$. Since $-(1+1/n)^n>-e$, then $x\in (-e,\infty)$. Let $x\in(-e,\infty)$, then $0<x+e$ and since $-(1+1/n)^n\searrow -e$, then there existes an $m$ with $-(1+1/m)^m+e<x+e$. So the equality holds.

A simpler/more general form of this isargument is the following: Let $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\searrow a$ (remember that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense and $\mathbb{R}$ is $1^\circ$ countable). Then $(a_n,\infty)\nearrow(a,\infty)\notin\tau$.